# Get All Images Name in Images folder in form of url

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have uploaded some images on my server in Images Folder i want path for Each images i.e like :

```
     www.minimicro.com/images/name1.png 
     www.minimicro.com/images/name2.png 
     www.minimicro.com/images/name2.png
```

I want C# Code to get all this in One String array.
help me for this.

thank you in Advance.

Comment: In web-server files are saved as we store on our computers, difference is you have access permission to your directory only. While uploading files to server better you make an entry to database(Strong your file name.), now you can retrieve the file-name from db and then use query-string like: www.minimicro.com/images?img=name1.png and so on... On post-back receive the file-name through query-string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with yhis code - based on `Directory.GetFiles` method and `Server.MapPath`

```
    var path = Server.MapPath("...");
    var images = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.png");
    foreach (var image in images) 
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(image);
    }
```

On the network you can also use `WebRequest` class

Link :http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnettips/article.php/c7005/Downloading-Files-with-the-WebRequest-and-WebResponse-Classes.htm

Comment: hii thanks for Reply this is Working Perfact locally but on server i need www.urlname.com/Image/Name1.jpg i want all images name in forms of url

Answer (score 0):

```
    DirectoryInfo _Di = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Img\desktop");
    var GetDirInfo = _Di.GetFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    if (GetDirInfo.Count() > 0)
    {

    }
```

try this... sure it will work.

Comment: hii thank for Reply but i want it in form of url that is www.maysitename/images/Name1.pngand all other same as this

Comment: @rohanpanchal you will be getting image file name right? just bind portalURL + image file name in a string that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get images inform URLs:

```
var path = Server.MapPath("...");
var images = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.png");
System.Collections.Generic.List<string> urls = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();
foreach (var image in images)
{
     urls.Add(string.Format("http://{0}/{1}", Request.Url.Authority, image));
}
```

Hope this will helps.